# how do i configure two forest with one exchange server

Tags: exchange-2010

I work for financial company; we have 9 branches, and each has its own AD forest.  I would like to install exchange server 2010 (in one domain), and use this installation of exchange to service email for all the users in all the branches.  Is this possible, and how can I make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

This would be helpful to review:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998031(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: Yes. Linked mailboxes is one way to do this.

Comment: You can do this without it being a resource forest as well.  You can setup the Exchange server within the HQ domain/forest for example and service it with real mailbox users and the rest of the forests can have linked mailboxes on that server.  I would also recommend the user look into Exchange Online/Office 365 if the company is willing to go that route.

Comment: I would also recommend if you do go this route that you consider setting it up in a VM in a virtualized farm of some kind or figure out a decent DR/HA policy if the company requires it.  There's also the possibility of slowdowns on your WAN between branches if there are large email attachments, etc. without proper tuning.